# Camel: Smooks Filtering operation failed

Tags: apache-camel, smooks

I'm working with camel and I'm trying to add a smooks transformation to my route:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("file:src/main/resources/smookFromCsvToXml/from?fileName=test.jtl")
        .log("Before SmooksComponent\n${body}")
        .to("smooks://smooks-config.xml")
        .to("file:src/main/resources/smookFromCsvToXml/to")
        .log("After SmooksComponent\n${body}");
}
```

when I run this route i get the following error

```
[sources/smookFromCsvToXml/from] route1                         INFO  Before SmooksComponent
Tom,Fennelly,Male,4,Ireland
Mike,Fennelly,Male,2,Ireland
[sources/smookFromCsvToXml/from] DefaultErrorHandler            ERROR Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-WM-WAMS-DAD-61818-1348228740355-0-15 on ExchangeId: ID-WM-WAMS-DAD-61818-1348228740355-0-14). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.milyn.SmooksException: Smooks Filtering operation failed.
org.milyn.SmooksException: Smooks Filtering operation failed.
    at org.milyn.Smooks._filter(Smooks.java:548)[milyn-smooks-all-1.5.1.jar:]
    at org.milyn.Smooks.filterSource(Smooks.java:482)[milyn-smooks-all-1.5.1.jar:]
    at org.milyn.smooks.camel.processor.SmooksProcessor.process(SmooksProcessor.java:107)[milyn-smooks-all-1.5.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint.onExchange(ProcessorEndpoint.java:101)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint$1.process(ProcessorEndpoint.java:71)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:120)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:292)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:115)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:71)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.fabric.FabricTraceProcessor.process(FabricTraceProcessor.java:81)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:330)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:220)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:304)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:117)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.processAsync(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:150)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:117)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.processNext(RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.java:50)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:71)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:388)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:198)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:159)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:140)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:92)[camel-core-2.9.0.fuse-70-084.jar:2.9.0.fuse-70-084]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)[:1.6.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)[:1.6.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)[:1.6.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)[:1.6.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)[:1.6.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)[:1.6.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)[:1.6.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)[:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)[:1.6.0_25]
[sources/smookFromCsvToXml/from] GenericFileOnCompletion        WARN  Rollback file strategy: org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy@1a779dce for file: GenericFile[test.jtl]
```

While my transformation if the following:

```
<smooks-resource-list 
    xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd" 
    xmlns:core="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/smooks-core-1.4.xsd"
    xmlns:csv="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/csv-1.2.xsd">

    <csv:reader fields="firstname,lastname,gender,age,country" rootElementName="people" recordElementName="person" />

    <core:exports>
        <core:result type="org.milyn.payload.StringResult"/>
    </core:exports>

</smooks-resource-list>
```

It seams that smooks cannot read the incoming message. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the message to a String beforehand maybe, eg adding before the smooks

```
<convertBodyTo type="String"/>
```

Comment: Ok that worked, but is that dangerous in case I process big files?

Comment: Then you know its a problem with smooks which can't work with the Camel file endpoint out of the box.

Comment: You can convert to an java.io.InputStream instead